# GWT SimplePager style not working after migrating to GWT 2.8

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.8

I recently upgraded my GWT web application from 2.3 to 2.8.1. Application is only up partially but some of the buttons are not working. I see following error in logs.

```
(TypeError): Cannot read property ‘classname’ of null
```

Issue is coming from the following  line of code:

```
firstPage.getElement().getParentElement().addClassName(style.button());
```

Where style is an instance of com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.SimplePager$Style

Please advise

Comment: Looks like your parent element is null. IS first page attached to the DOM? Btw, why not moving to GWT 2.9.0?

Comment: Is there a way to check if my firstPage is attached to the DOM?
For your other question about using 2.9.0, my organization only approved 2.8 but not 2.9.0 yet.

Comment: Run your app using SDM and enable 'Pause on caught exception' in Chrome. But I am pretty sure it is not.

Comment: For some reason I am unable to run my application in SDM. I don’t see any errors in console, able to build it properly. But when I run http://127.0.0.1:9876 I see: GWT Code Server

Drag these two bookmarklets to your browser’s bookmark bar: Dev Mode On Dev Mode Off
Visit a web page that uses one of these modules: <MY_MODULE>
When I click on my module, I see “this module hasn’t been compiled yet”.

Comment: Run 127.0.0.1:8080/index.html or 127.0.0.1:8888/index.html to start your application. That should start SDM.

Comment: When I run using “gwt:run-codeserver” from eclipse and open 127.0.0.1:8080/index.html or 127.0.0.1:8888/index.html it is not recognizing those ports at all. Getting “Can’t reach this page” error. When I run using “gwt:run” from eclipse and open 127.0.0.1:8080/index.html or 127.0.0.1:8888/index.html browser is giving 503 error.

Comment: Depending on the set up of your project (single or multi module) run mvn gwt:devmode in case of a single module project or mvn gwt:codeserver & mvn jetty:run. But, without having more informations about your project setup it is hard to say. Try to discuss your problem here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt